# HttpGet returning error 400 'Bad Request' for certain phones

Tags: android

I have a class that gets JSON objects from my app's website.
Unfortunately I've come across a problem where certain phones get an error 400 'Bad Request' result code, and most phones work just fine with this code.

Anyone know who this doesn't work for all phones ?

```
public class MyAppJSON {
    private String params;

    public MyAppJSON(String params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    public JSONObject readJSON() {
        JSONObject result = null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.myapp.com/json.php?action=" + this.params);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.e(MyAppJSON.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
            }
            result = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are those devices maybe running Android HC+?

Comment: I'm sorry what's HC+ ? I don't have a way of telling if they do since they're not my phones.

They're phones of people who had this bug, one of which was kind enough to lend me his phone to debug it.

Comment: HC+ = Honeycomb and upwards.

Comment: What I meant to ask was, if you are using an Asynctask to load your data or not.

Comment: 1. Yes the app supports HC+.
2. In this case the http request is not in an asynctask but others in the app are.
3. My phone with ICS is working fine with it.